# Doctrine Insert em relação Many-to-Many unidirecional

Tags: zend, doctrine, sql-insert

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Na minha entidade Local:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Contato")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="contato_localidade",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="localidade_id", referencedColumnName="identificador")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="contato_id", referencedColumnName="identificador")}
 *      )
 * */
protected $contatos;
```

Na entidade Contato não há mapeamento para Local.
Um local sempre é cadastro primeiro, um contato é adicionado a ele posteriormente.

O problema é o seguinte: como salvar esta relação?
Todas as relação que eu vi usam uma função attach(), mas não consegui usá-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você possui uma relação `ManyToMany` entre as entidades `Contato` e `Local`, sendo que somente a entidade `Local` referencia a entidade `Contato` (ou seja, é uma relação unidirecional).

Na prática, cada uma de suas entidades será inicializada com um objeto do tipo quando você possui um objeto do tipo `ArrayCollection`, é normal o Doctrine gerar métodos `get`, `set`, `add` e `remove` para aquela propriedade. Assim, suas classes ficariam assim:

```
<?php

class Local
{
    private $contatos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->contatos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public funcion addContato(Contato $contato)
    {
        $this->contatos->add($contato);
    }

    public function removeContato(Contato $contato)
    {
        $this->contatos->remove($contato);
    }

    public function getContatos()
    {
        return $this->contatos;
    }

    public function setContatos($contatos)
    {
        $this->contatos = $contatos;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

e

```
<?php

class Contato
{
    private $locais;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->locais = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public funcion addLocal(Local $local)
    {
        $this->locais->add($local);
    }

    public function removeLocal(Local $local)
    {
        $this->locais->remove($local);
    }

    public function getLocais()
    {
        return $this->locais;
    }

    public function setLocais($locais)
    {
        $this->locais = $locais;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

O que você precisa fazer, posteriormente, ao adicionar um `Contato` a um `Local`, é pegar sua variável `$local` (que possui um `ArrayCollection` de contatos, mesmo que vazio) e adicionar um `$contato` a ele por meio do método `Local::addContato(Contato $contato)`.

```
$local = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Local')->findOneById($localId);

$contato = new Contato();
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($contato);

$local->addContato($contato);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($local);

$local->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```